# JAXB - How to serialize fields in a subclass of a collection

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm having trouble serializing the fields in my class, which is a subclass of ArrayList.   The items added to the list are serialized, but the fields aren't:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public static class NumberedList extends ArrayList<String>{

    @XmlAttribute
    private int number = 5;

    @XmlList
    public List<String> getNames(){
        return this;
    }

    public NumberedList(){
        add("a");
        add("b");
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public static class FieldTest{

    @XmlElement
    NumberedList list = new NumberedList();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FieldTest.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(new FieldTest(), System.out);
}
```

//Output from serializing the NumberedList as a field: no number field is present

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><fieldTest><list>a</list><list>b</list></fieldTest>
```

The strange thing is that when I add the list to a Map, the fields in my class get serialized as I expect them to.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public static class NumberedList extends ArrayList<String>{

    @XmlAttribute
    private int number = 5;

    @XmlList
    public List<String> getNames(){
        return this;
    }

    public NumberedList(){
        add("a");
        add("b");
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public static class MapTest{
    @XmlElement
    Map<Integer, NumberedList> map = Maps.newHashMap();

    public MapTest(){
        map.put(1, new NumberedList());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MapTest.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(new MapTest(), System.out);
}
```

//Output from serializing the NumberedList in a Map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><mapTest><map><entry><key>1</key><value number="5"><names>a b</names></value></entry></map></mapTest>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that `NumberedList` is extending `ArrayList`. Add an internal `ArrayList` to the class and then serialize it along with other fields that exist in `NumberedList`. See the below code:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class NumberedList {
    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    @XmlAttribute
    private int number = 5;

    public NumberedList(){
        names.add("a");
        names.add("b");
    }

    @XmlList
    public List<String> getNames(){
        return names;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i am seeing in two classes you have root element.. which is fundamentally wrong.. you can have only one root element .. so remove it form NumberedList. in second step i see you are intializing the map

```
public MapTest(){
        map.put(1, new NumberedList());
    }
```

where as in first you are not doing ..