# Jackson, how to expose fields when serializing a class which extend a collection?

Tags: jackson

I have a class that we use for paginated results, as follows:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {

    private int offset;
    private int count;
    private int totalResultCount;

    //...
}
```

and I'd like Jackson to serialize it like this:

```
{
  "results":[1,2,3],
  "offset":0,
  "count":3,
  "totalResultCount":15
}
```

(*where the parent list contains the three integer values 1,2 and 3.*)

In my first attempt I discovered that Jackson effectively ignores any properties on classes which are assignable to a Collection class.  In hindsight, this makes sense, and so I'm now in search of a workaround.  A search of SO resulted in two similar questions:

- [jackson-serialization-includes-subclasss-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276479/jackson-serialization-includes-subclasss-fields)
- [jaxb-how-to-serialize-fields-in-a-subclass-of-a-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924848/jaxb-how-to-serialize-fields-in-a-subclass-of-a-collection)

However, both of these resulted in the suggestion to switch from inheritance to composition.

I am specifically looking for **a solution that allows the class to extend a collection**.  This 'PaginatedList' class is part of the common core of the enterprise, and extends Collection so that it can be used (and introspected) as a collection throughout the code.  Changing to composition isn't an option.  That being said, I am free to annotate and otherwise change this class to support serialization as I described above.

So, from what I can tell, there's two parts I'm missing (what I'm looking for in an answer):

1. How to get Jackson to 'see' the added properties?
2. How to get Jackson to label the collection's content as a 'results' property in the JSON output?

(*PS: I'm only concerned with serialization.*)

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers - may be one route - make your own serialisation for this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ashley Frieze pointed this out in a comment, and deserves the credit for this answer.

I solved this by creating a JsonSerializer instance as follows:

```
public class PaginatedListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PaginatedList> {

    @Override
    public Class<PaginatedList> handledType() {
        return PaginatedList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(PaginatedList value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();

        jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("results");
        for (Object entry : value) {
            jgen.writeObject(entry);
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
        jgen.writeNumberField("offset", value.offset);
        jgen.writeNumberField("count", value.count);
        jgen.writeNumberField("totalResultCount", value.totalResultCount);

        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

and, of course, register it as a module:

```
SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("PaginatedListSerializerModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
testModule.addSerializer(new PaginatedListSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(testModule);
```